# Gradle native-platform posix files is not available

Tags: gradle

Downloaded gradle from official site, install it. type in command line:

```
gradle -v - it's ok
```

type

```
gradle tasks or gradle --daemon hello - gets an error!
```

How I undestand with many hours of trying - daemon not started in cause not correct jvm parameter or jvm ("unrecognize jvm...").

Computer - AMD Core2Duo 2Gz, 4Gb RAM.
Screens applied.

USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Please, anybody help me!

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krQVJ.jpg)
[incubating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3wLY.jpg)

Comment: That don't helps me. Now 102 version of JDK.

Comment: Solved by reinstall Windows.